# Is the number 7 magical in the HP universe?

Tags: harry-potter

> "...isn't [seven](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Seven) the most powerfully magical number, wouldn't seven-?"

Well is it? The list link lacks...magic, most of the events being mundane or even coincidental.

Edit; because the question is fairly trivial without this change: Are there any examples of the number seven being magical in nature? In particular is there any actual magical advantage to having 7 horcruxes, or is it just sentiment?