# Why didn't Harry leave the Dursleys' house under the Invisibility Cloak instead of having the Seven Potters plan?

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak

In order to get Harry out of the Dursleys' house, the aurors decided to come up with a plan to use polyjuice potion to create seven Harry Potters, providing confusion over who the Death Eaters should go after. This was to avoid the problem of apparating out of the house, since Harry still had the Trace and the Ministry would know where he went. (Floo powder and portkeys also had some Ministry oversight, so were off the table).

Why didn't Harry just leave while wearing the Invisibility Cloak, perhaps going out at the same time that the Dursleys were moving out? That doesn't involve casting any spells and nobody can see Harry. So long as he's smart enough to get out without having any strangely opening doors, I think he'd be safe. Heck, since the Cloak is large enough to cover three children, perhaps he could even ride his broomstick while wearing it. Sure, there's the *homenum revelio* spell, but I can't imagine the Death Eaters casting it continuously for days on end.

Why didn't Harry leave the Dursleys' house under the Invisibility Cloak instead of having the Seven Potters plan?

Comment: @JasonBaker I saw that question in the list, but had no idea that it would be a duplicate. I edited the title of that question to make it easier to find. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I actually saw [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31058/31051) in the sidebar on this question, and saw it had been closed as a dupe of the other one; good edit